# E aquelas perguntas que não tem tags?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Vi que temos uma *tag* chamada [untagged](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), atualmente com 9 perguntas, a qual acredito que seja utilizada para as perguntas desgarradas presentes no site.

Entretanto, acredito que poderíamos eliminar essa *tag* e classificar as perguntas se possível, em seus devidos lugares. A mesma coisa de sempre, fechar o que tiver que ser fechado, e editar o que puder ser editado.

Julgo ser necessário por alguns motivos, principalmente porque já temos um grande número de tecnologias disponíveis através das *tags*, e porque uma *tag* como essa pode abrir espaço para questões fora de escopo e/ou principalmente baseadas em opiniões.

Então, o que acham? Procede uma limpeza e possível eliminação da *tag* [untagged](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)?

---

Não seria mais proveitoso marcar a pergunta [Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8116/1658), com a *tag* [terminologia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminologia) ao invés de [mercado-de-trabalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercado-de-trabalho)?

Comment: São perguntas migradas daqui do meta ou de outros sites da rede.

Comment: Mas não seria interessante classificá-las corretamente mesmo vindas de outro site? E nem todas são, algumas o AP marcou diretamente na criação. @Articuno

Comment: Eu particulamente acho perda de tempo, são perguntas antigas e algumas fechadas.

Comment: Eu fico neurótico com as coisas sem tag, por mais que não se produza algo muito útil no final, pelo menos fica tudo mais encaixadinho...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu editei sete das nove perguntas para que tivessem as *tags* corretas. Três ou quatro delas exigiram a criação de novas *tags*. Para o restante as *tags* necessárias já existiam.

Sobraram apenas duas:

- [**BigPipe seria aplicável nesse caso?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91771/1658) - eu não sei qual ou quais *tags* seriam adequadas nesse caso;
- [**Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior? [fechada]**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8116/1658) - essa pergunta deveria ser removida do site, mas infelizmente não pode ser removida agora porque outra pergunta foi marcada como duplicata dela. Votei pela remoção da duplicata ([**Níveis de Programador [duplicada]**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89823/1658)) - ainda faltam dez votos. Quando a duplicata, que também acho ser inadequada para o site for removida, poderemos remover a outra.

Comment: A questão do BigPipes com certeza se encaixa na tag de desempenho

Comment: A pergunta é tão fora de contexto que as tags da duplicada são "aplicação-web" e "desempenho". Entretanto não sei qual o critério para remoção dessas perguntas, acho que é um caso que merece um tópico no meta só para ele.