# Realmente precisamos remover certas perguntas "off-topic"?

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas, perguntas-apagadas

Vejo perguntas off-topic que ao meu ver me parecem que geraram boas respostas, como esta:

> [Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8116/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-trainee-j%C3%BAnior-pleno-s%C3%AAnior)

A pergunta já esta fechada como podem ver, mas mesmo assim levou 3 votos (até o momento) para remoção, presumo que o sejam uma daquelas atitudes da fila de analise de certos usuários inexperientes (não posso afirmar nada)

Mas falando em geral, realmente é necessário? O fechamento não seria mais que suficiente, principalmente quando gera algumas boas respostas (falando de qualquer pergunta além do exemplo citado)?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6483/64969

Comment: Eliminando ou não a pergunta, (talvez) ainda precisamos classificá-la corretamente.

Comment: Coloquei uma flag para moderador na pergunta: "*Bloquear/congelar a pergunta como conteúdo histórico.*" - Daqui a pouco algum moderador avalia isso. Acho que essa é a melhor alternativa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa moderadores limpam e cuidam do conteudo, como spam e certos problemas, esse tipo de situação é relativa e não penso que seja obrigação de moderadores, mas sim opinião da comunidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/8116/revisions - Olha isso, ela já foi deletada antes e o Gabe trouxe de volta. Além disso, não é bom para o SO como empresa apagar perguntas com uma grande quantidade de votos e de visualizações, e esse tipo de bloqueio foi inventado para resolver pepinos como esse.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, estou ciente, mas o que digo é que não penso que isso seja "tarefa" de moderadores (ao menos não preocupação principal), mas sim da comunidade junta.

Comment: "Olha isso, ela já foi deletada antes e o Gabe trouxe de volta" - ou seja, realmente nem deveria estar no site (IMHO). Eu não lembrava disso, mais um "reforço" pra ela não estar, afinal de contas se há a necessidade de bloquear, claramente é para contrariar o "risco" da comunidade levar a coisa pro seu curso natural ;)

Comment: E agora ficou pior :( tem uma tag claramente off-topic no site!

Comment: @VictorStafusa O bloqueio é mesmo uma solução adequada se a decisão final for manter a pergunta. Eu ainda estou em dúvida, porque ela é bem off-topic. Se pelo menos as respostas focassem na área de tecnologia, vá lá, mas aquele conteúdo é tão genérico que serve para qualquer área. Então fico pensando se isso tem mesmo lugar num site sobre programação. Tô no muro.

Comment: Pergunta temporariamente bloqueada para dar espaço à discussão. Senão ela ia acabar removida nas próximas horas e quem tem menos de 10k seria deixado de fora do debate.

Comment: @Bacco Fiz isso para que ela não ficasse com o "untagged". Por outro lado, dá para se monitorar essa tag de forma que se alguém crie perguntas nela, já receba tratamento VIP na fila de fechamento.

Comment: @VictorStafusa a sim entendi o motivo de trocar a tag, mas será que não seria melhor fazer isso depois do debate ou de chegarmos a uma conclusão mais próxima?

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu preferia o untagged (que é assunto de outra questão do meta, por acaso) mas entendo a motivação. É que eu já vi mais de uma vez discussão aqui de que "a pergunta está no escopo pq o site tem determinada tag", então gosto de evitar :) De qq forma, aguardemos para ver onde a coisa vai parar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Feito

Comment: @Math excelente :D

Answer (score 13):

O motivo pelo qual votei pela remoção (fui o terceiro a votar) é o escopo.

De acordo com a central de ajuda, a pergunta está dentro do escopo se ela é sobre:

> - um problema específico de programação (no check)
> - um algoritmo de software (no check)
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores (no check)
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software (no check)
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software (no check)

Ainda de acordo com a central, uma pergunta está fora de escopo quando:

> - toda resposta seja igualmente válida (check)
> - sua resposta seja fornecida junto com a pergunta e você espera mais respostas (discutivelmente check<sup>1</sup>)
> - não haja um problema real para resolver (check)
> - você faça uma pergunta hipotética e aberta (check)
> - sua pergunta seja apenas uma fanfarrice disfarçada (no check)

De dez pontos analisados, pelo menos oito indicam que ela está fora do escopo do site.

O fato de ter boas respostas não deveria ser justificativa para mantê-la. Eu poderia fazer uma pergunta sobre "lista de filmes que envolvem conceitos de computação"; E as pessoas poderiam responder coisas como "Matrix, O Fantasma do Futuro, Johny 5, Eu Robô" etc. Poderiam ser respostas excelentes, com crítica de cinema, boas fontes sobre a inspiração dos autores, explicações sobre os conceitos abordados... Mas ainda não seria uma boa pergunta para o site. Não ajuda ninguém a resolver um problema prático.

Nós podemos usar o argumento de que mantê-la, mesmo fechada, serve de exemplo do tipo de pergunta que não deve ser feito. Podemos utilizá-la para marcar novas perguntas do tipo como duplicata. Mas ao fazer isso nós acabamos por manter uma pergunta que, além de não estar alinhada com o site, tem a *tag* mais absurda de todas.

Por fim, acredito que mantê-la para marcar novas perguntas como duplicatas tem mais um aspecto tóxico. Isso faz com que perguntas similares sejam fechadas indicando duplicidade e não pelo motivo correto, que é o formato em desalinhamento com o SO. Isso pode dar uma impressão errada sobre porque uma pergunta não é boa quando analisamos o motivo do fechamento.

<sup>1</sup> A pergunta indica no título quatro funções de carreira, para em seguida perguntar quais funções existem. A publicação também termina com uma pergunta praticamente auto-respondida.

Comment: Entendo, é um bom argumento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não é que eu não goste da pergunta - eu gosto. Eu só acho que é o tipo de coisa que se pergunta no Quora e não no SE.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo até compartilho da opinião, claro que ainda estou em cima do [**muro**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akbf6.png) com tudo isto :)

Comment: Não tinha visto sua resposta quando escrevi a minha, mas concordo justamente com o `mantê-la, mesmo fechada, serve de exemplo do tipo de pergunta que não deve ser feito`, e concordo que não devemos usá-la para marcar duplicadas, que deverão ser fechadas como off-topic. Sobre a analogia com a lista de filmes, não acho válida pois dificilmente uma pergunta assim teria sobrevivido por tanto tempo e ganhado o destaque que ela ganhou, não sabemos como mas de uma forma ou de outraa pergunta em questão vingou e recebeu respostas justamente daqueles que têm mais reputação no site. Voto para mantê-la.

Answer (score 10):

Ela é um mau exemplo de pergunta e não deve ser referência para novas perguntas no site, mas por ter recebido tantos votos, tantas visitas e tantas respostas também bem votadas, eu sou a favor de mantê-la no site.

A modificação que faria nela seria bloqueá-la por significância histórica, basicamente será uma nota de rodapé nela que diz o seguinte:

> Esta pergunta existe porque possui significância histórica, mas não é considerada uma boa pergunta no tópico para este site; portanto, não a utilize como um sinal de que você pode fazer perguntas similares aqui. Esta pergunta e suas respostas estão congeladas e não podem ser alteradas. Mais informações central de ajuda

Ao receber o bloqueio a pergunta e as respostas ficam impossibilitadas de serem editadas, removidas ou até mesmo votadas, deixando-as congeladas da forma que estiverem no momento do bloqueio. Um exemplo de pergunta bloqueada por significância histórica é a do Victor Stafusa no site Programming Puzzles & Code Golf: [I need a program where the user inputs an array of doubles and the program outputs the array sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16226)

Comment: As setas não somem, mas acho que não dá mais para usá-las.

Comment: Falta 1 voto pra remover, mas essa idéia é ótima tambem, é possivel vocês fazerem isso ou precisa do CM?

Comment: @Articuno os mods conseguem fazer isso, e também conseguem restaurar caso seja removida, se a ideia tiver apoio, é claro

Comment: olha, me parece a melhor saída! :D

Comment: Eu não vejo significância histórica nenhuma nela. Me parece mais uma desculpa pra deixar. Teve coisa muito melhor removida já. Inclusive, logo depois do desbloqueio temporário já veio mais um voto de remover, se não me engano. Creio que a solução é deixar a comunidade fazer o que deve. Se realmente é boa, não vão aparecer os votos pra remover.

Comment: @Bacco a ideia é justamente deixar para a comunidade resolver e esse é o propósito desse post no meta. Entretanto medir a vontade da comunidade por quantidade de votos de remoção não me parece o melhor pois não temos votos para "não remoção" para ter uma comparação justa, e uma vez apagada ela sai de vista e dificilmente será restaurada espontaneamente pelos usuários. Enquanto isso a discussão segue em aberto, sugiro inclusive que você poste seus argumentos para remoção em forma de resposta para sustentar seu ponto, que acho extremamente válido.

Comment: @Math Confirmo que as setas de votação somem. Inclusive há uma pergunta minha bloqueada como histórica no code-golf.

Comment: @VictorStafusa valeu pelo exemplo, editei a resposta