# Minha pergunta foi fechada, mas teve boa votação, como devo proceder para reabertura?

Tags: debate

Fiz esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184059/certificados-ssl-gratuito-let-s-encrypt-tem-a-mesma-confiabilidade-dos-pagos) há alguns meses pois não encontrei nada fora do Stack Overflow.

Ela realmente não fala sobre programação em si, mas se trata de um assunto que vem ganhando destaque, pois Firefox e Google Chrome pretendem dificultar o acesso a sites sem certificados.

A pergunta, eu a referi como desenvolvedor e minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Realmente ela não tem fundamento para ficar aberta? Ou existe outro site da **Stack Exchange** para tratar este tipo de assunto? Agradeço quem puder me explicar melhor, pois tenho outras dúvidas sobre implantação.

Comment: Tem duas cheklists [nessa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6496/64969), a primeira é para assuntos no tópico, a segunda é para assuntos fora do tópico. Eu creio que se encaixe em diversos pontos para ser considerado no tópico, pois é um problema/dúvida de deploy da aplicação. Então eu acho que é candidata sim a reabertura.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado por isso eu abri o debate pois creio que está válida, valeu.

Comment: O problema é o mesmo que das perguntas jurídicas (licenciamento etc). Por exemplo, a resposta dada teve vários positivos mas não abrange praticamente nada da essência do Let's Encrypt (que é justamente a filosofia do sistema, que é o certificado renovado sem intervenção humana e por isso o prazo curto). Tem outros problemas além desse, que nao discuti lá justamente por ser fora de escopo. Quando as perguntas saem do escopo, tendem a ter votação inadequada e respostas inadequadas, por falta de especialistas no assunto, baixando a qualidade do material do site e podendo levar usuários a enganos.

Comment: Creio eu que só a ultima pergunta *"Ou como desenvolvedor devo utilizar estes certificados apenas para testar as aplicações, e quando houver a homologação do cliente devo fazer a contratação?"* seria respondível sem acabar caindo nos possíveis enganos citados pelo @Bacco, e a apesar da resposta do Daniel ter sido bem técnica (o que parece ser bom) ela não torna sua pergunta "válida", o assunto continua sendo o nivel de confiabilidade entre X e Y, logo é algo que não da para afirmar, novas resposta podem acabar caindo até no nível "comercial" ao invés de "técnico".

Comment: Creio eu que essa edição inclusive talvez caberia melhor em uma nova pergunta, sem usar aquele titulo e sem usar aquela introdução.

Comment: Ok, pessoal entendi, os comentários e as respostas, e vou fazer outra pergunta @GuilhermeNascimento conforme sua dica, pois ainda fiquei na dúvida se é aconselhável ou não usar em deploy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que costumamos dizer aos utilizadores que nos contactam em relação a como reabrir a sua pergunta fechada, para além de que podem sempre pedir ajuda à comunidade aqui como fizeste para entrar em detalhes específicos sobre aquela pergunta em particular, é o seguinte:

> Mesmo que já tenhas alterado a pergunta, recomendamos que leias [esta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ver se consegues melhor a pergunta ainda mais. Tem em consideração que boas perguntas tendem a ter mais atenção, o que por sua vez significa melhores chances de ter boas respostas para esta.
>
> Se tiveres o privilégio de votar para abrir/fechar perguntas, podes votar para a reabrir directamente na pergunta. Como com uma edição, isto vai fazer com que a pergunta aparece na fila de “Votos para reabrir” para que outros membros da comunidade possam vê-la. Nota, no entanto, que algumas perguntas [são fora de escopo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), e portanto não melhoráveis por definição.

Deixo aqui isto para que fique aqui alguma noção de como se deve proceder no caso geral, não entrando em detalhes sobre se esta pergunta em particular pertence a este site ou não.

Answer (score 2):

Votei para remover sem querer. Votei para reabrir também.

A introdução da pergunta é desnecessária e você pode removê-la. Acho que as pessoas que votaram para fechar fizeram o seguinte julgamento, o que é perfeitamente compreensível:

> A pergunta do AP se resume a saber se o certificado de uma empresa específica é confiável ou não.

Eu pensei da mesma forma quando li a pergunta. E isso acaba sendo algo que não é sobre programação, e questão de opinião.

Acontece que existem, sim, diferenças importantes entre o certificado da Let's Encrypt e de outras empresas, incusive envolvendo programação - com relação a **tempo de validade**,

### **suporte de navegadores**,

se a validação é **por domínio ou por organização**, se dá **suporte a caractere coringa** etc.

Todas essas características devem ser levadas em conta antes de se colocar um certificado SSL em uso. Acho que devemos reabrir a questão, ela merece uma boa resposta. Se eu não tiver tempo de escrever uma, eu pelo menos dou uma recompensa depois.

**Edit:** agora que vi, tem uma resposta muito boa lá.