# Pergunta sobre orçamento de projetos deveria ser off-topic, não?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Me deparei com esta pergunta, creio que talvez eu não tenha dado atenção pra ela antes, mas ao notar uma pergunta que hoje foi duplicada desta acabei por nota-la:

- [Como fazer o orçamento inicial de um projeto de software?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23185/3635)

Revendo um caso semelhante:

- [Realmente precisamos remover certas perguntas "off-topic"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6495/3635)

Eu acho que ambas vão de encontro com o off-topic, no entanto ambas eram muito bem aceitas, ainda sim a decisão da outra postagem foi marcar como **bloqueada**:

> Esta pergunta existe porque possui significância histórica, mas não é considerada uma boa pergunta no tópico para este site; portanto, não a utilize como um sinal de que você pode fazer perguntas similares aqui. Esta pergunta e suas respostas estão congeladas e não podem ser alteradas.

Penso que o caso da pergunta sobre orçamento de software seja também bloquear. O que acham?

Comment: Acho que deveriam ser sim fechadas. Isso não afeta em nada o fato delas serem significadamente importantes historicamente para o site, mas o principal é que abertas, poderão ser usadas como incentivo para que outros usuários criem perguntas idênticas.

Comment: @Articuno também acho

Comment: Em teoria vocês dois (Guilherme + @Articuno) até têm razão, mas vejam bem: essas perguntas estão no site há 3 anos e não dá pra dizer que aparecem muitas do tipo... Então até podemos colocar o bloqueio, mas não acho que a presença dessas duas esteja realmente causando qualquer problema.