# Duas vezes uma pergunta sobre R veio erroneamente para o meta

Tags: debate

Duas perguntas sobre criar exemplos reproduzíveis no R foram migradas para o meta erroneamente:

[Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-sobre-r-no-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Notem que essas são perguntas de programação. Elas envolvem colocar semente para números aleatórios, recuperar a estrutura dos dados, recuperar informações do sistema. Essas são perguntas sobre código em R. São completamente off-topic no meta. Imagina alguém vir aqui no meta e perguntar: como garantir que os números aleatórios sejam sempre os mesmos em C++? Evidentemente que a pergunta não seria pertinente para o meta.

Enfim, essas não são perguntas sobre o site em si, apesar de o site servir como contexto. Essas técnicas são úteis para qualquer momento em que alguém precise criar um exemplo reproduzível em R.

Sugiro escolher uma dessas duas perguntas, transformar em wiki da comunidade e transferir para o site principal. Da forma como estão, aqui no meta, elas não cumprem nenhum papel.

PS: também sinalizei as duas perguntas para atenção dos moderadores, com o intuito de levar uma delas para o site principal como wiki da comunidade.

Comment: Achava que já tinha lido uma pergunta como a de ontem, procurei na comunidade principal e para minha surpresa não achei nada. Agora sei porquê. E [o problema vai se repetir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+exemplo).

Comment: Eu tenho 2 pontos. 1) Não adiantava migrar a pergunta para cá e não mesclar com a primeira (ou pelo menos marcar como duplicata). 2) Aparentemente a comunidade R está aprovando esta pergunta no site principal. Será que não é o caso de abrir uma exceção ao que é considerado dentro do escopo para o site como um todo? (Pelo que eu saiba, as regras aqui tendem a ser bem flexíveis, se não fossem, já teria um robô para classificar se a pergunta está dentro ou fora do escopo.)

Answer (score 5):

> Imagina alguém vir aqui no meta e perguntar: como garantir que os números aleatórios sejam sempre os mesmos em C++?

Nesse caso a pergunta vai pro site principal em um piscar de olhos. Mas note que *"como faço para gerar números aleatórios de um jeito específico?"* é diferente de (verbatim):

> quais são as principais características de uma boa pergunta sobre R?

...e de (também verbatim):

> existe algo que deve ser evitado em uma pergunta sobre R?

As duas indagações acima são da [segunda pergunta mencionada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6700/1658). Desconheço [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), mas por experiência acredito que se a central de ajuda não contiver a resposta, terá pelo menos a base sobre a qual uma indicação pode ser feita.

Para ser justo, nessa pergunta, há sim uma indagação que pode **discutivelmente** ser adequada para o site principal:

> como o usuário pode compartilhar os dados analisados (ou uma parte deles) com a comunidade?

Para uma forma programática, ferramental ou processual (ainda que em esboço) de como se compartilhar os dados, eu acho que pode ficar no site principal mesmo. Mas se a discussão ficar muito no "publica no site X", estará fora do foco do SO.

A [primeira pergunta mencionada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/1658) também possui três indagações:

> - O que deve ter em exemplo reproduzível mínimo?
> - Que informações devem ser colocadas?
> - Quais funções do R podem ajudar a fazer um exemplo reproduzível?

Novamente, as duas primeiras indagações são comuns a todas as perguntas e independentes de tecnologia.

> O que deve ter em exemplo reproduzível mínimo?
> Que informações devem ser colocadas?

A central de ajuda tem [um artigo sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> ### Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável
>
> Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Esse código deve ser…
>
> - …Mínimo – Use o mínimo possível de código capaz de reproduzir o problema
> - …Completo – Forneça todas as partes necessárias para se reproduzir o problema
> - …Verificável - Teste o código antes de postar para confirmar que ele reproduz o problema
>
> #### Mínimo
>
> Quanto maior o código, menor a chance de alguém enxergar o problema. Simplifique seu exemplo usando uma destas técnicas:
>
> Recomece do zero. Crie um novo programa, e só inclua nele o necessário para reproduzir o problema. Isso pode ser mais rápido para grandes sistemas, quando você acredita saber a origem do problema. Também é útil se não puder postar o código em público por razões legais ou éticas.
>
> Dividir e conquistar. Se o código for pequeno, mas você não tem ideia da causa do problema, comece a remover um pedaço de código por vez até que o problema suma – e então inclua essa última parte de volta.
>
> #### Mínimo e legível
>
> Mínimo não quer dizer necessariamente o mais conciso possível – um exemplo claro é melhor que um exemplo pequeno. Use nomes e indentação consistentes, e se necessário inclua comentários para explicar partes do código. Praticamente todos os editores de código têm um um comando de autoformatação – encontre e use! E não use tabs – elas podem aparecer bem no seu editor, mas no Stack Overflow podem sair bagunçadas.

E novamente, a terceira indagação cabe no site principal:

> Quais funções do R podem ajudar a fazer um exemplo reproduzível?

Acredito que o problema das duas perguntas foi ter misturado conteúdo para o site principal com conteúdo para o Meta. Se cada pergunta for modificada para conter apenas a parte focada em código e não em como pergunta, aí sim sou a favor de voltarem para o site principal.

A título de exemplo: no SO em inglês houve esses mesmos questionamentos. Lá a [pergunta técnica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2263584) ficou no site principal e a [meta-pergunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315885/2263584) ficou no Meta.

Comment: Eu votei negativo para expressar que discordo. Por favor leia o meu comentário na pergunta.

Comment: @DanielFalbel Achei boa a sugestão do Renan de separar o que é conteúdo técnico de metaconteúdo. Assim a parte meta fica no meta e a parte técnica no site principal, com links entre elas se necessário. Não estou entendendo o motivo da resistência da comunidade R quanto a isso.

Comment: Podemos fazer dessa forma. Pelo outro lado, não entendo porque a pergunta do jeito que está não pode ficar lá, dado que a comunidade está aceitando. A motivação me parece ser meramente burocrática e não pensando em como isso ajudaria as pessoas - ou em como atrapalharia.

Comment: @DanielFalbel não se trata de burocracia, mas sim de modelo. O que fez com que o Stack Overflow alcançasse o sucesso que tem foi o formato de Q&A e o foco. Se a gente abrir uma exceção pra uma comunidade, tem que abrir pra todas... Daí para nos aproximarmos ao formato de outros sites como o Quora é um salto.

Comment: Meu ponto é: qual a diferença de ter uma pergunta no Meta + uma pergunta no principal com links entre elas (no fim respondendo a mesma coisa) e ter uma pergunta só, no site principal com todo conteúdo? Para mim, por analogia, se não tem problema em 1) também não tem problema em 2)

Comment: São duas coisas diferentes sendo perguntadas. Uma pergunta é sobre metaconteúdo e a outra pergunta é sobre programação. O fato de não haver problema quando as perguntas estão separadas não implica na ausência de um problema caso estejam mescladas em uma só.

Comment: Não são duas coisas, o objetivo de todas indagações é o mesmo. (Criar um exemplo mínimo, reproduzível no R). A única diferença são as palavras. Uma contém as palavras `funções em R` a outra contém `pergunta na comunidade R`.

Comment: Note que nem estamos discutindo as respostas - que provavelmente serão as mesmas não importa como a pergunta for formulada. A resposta não vai ser tão objetiva- mas aí tudo bem, pq pelo menos respondeu o que foi perguntado (e a pergunta está dentro do escopo).

Comment: @DanielFalbel a meu ver, uma pergunta é sobre como montar um exemplo mínimo (sem indagação técnica alguma), o que é independente de tecnologia. A outra pergunta é sobre como prover exemplos com R. No SO em inglês, onde o pessoal é mais experiente, eles souberam diferenciar direito e lá tem perguntas sobre como lidar com R no Meta e sobre como prover um MCVE no site principal.

Comment: @Renan Sobre sua última frase, é isso mesmo ou ao contrário?

Comment: @bfavaretto é isso mesmo: [pergunta técnica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) no principal e [meta-pergunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow) no Meta.

Comment: nao faz nem sentido comparar os 2. a pergunta no site original de 2k votos a do meta tem 10. a do meta esta falando sobre dados no so, a outra esta falando sobre exemplo minimo reproduzivel ( que inclui os dados)

Comment: @DanielFalbel Por essa ordem de ideias poderíamos criar uma "Como criar um exemplo minimo reproduzível em Java" e o mesmo para todas as linguagens, repetindo o mesmo conteúdo em N perguntas quase iguais. Sendo assim a sugestão do Renan parece me a melhor. Na minha optica tudo o que está relacionado com formulação de perguntas/respostas faz parte do meta

Comment: @isac poderia, mas o conteudo seria completamente diferente para cada linguagem. criar um exemplo reproduzivel nao é exclusivo para formular perguntas, também é uma forma de debugar código, compartilhar codigo com colegas, etc. cada linguagem possui as suas particularidades e pontos mais importantes para se preocupar na hora de fazer um bom exemplo minimo.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogando um pouco com o argumento mais forte colocado pelo @Renan:

> A central de ajuda tem [um artigo sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

O artigo apontado é ótimo e eu não mudaria uma virgula sequer nele, mas ele tem eficácia limitada para o `R` por dois motivos.

O primeiro deles diz respeito ao fato de que de um modo geral quem começa a programar em `R`, e esta pergunta é direcionada principalmente para iniciantes, não vem de uma cultura de ciência da computação e similares. São biólogos, nutricionistas, estatísticos, economistas e outras diversas profissões que apenas querem utilizar um software estatístico para desempenhar esta ou aquela tarefa.

O segundo motivo diz respeito ao fato de que fornecer os dados com os quais se está trabalhando é fundamental para que o problema possa ser reproduzido. Há [mais de um forma de fazer isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6701/43953) e desejamos conduzir a comunidade para que adote as melhores práticas. Além disso, esta é a maior fonte da irreprodutibilidade das perguntas.

A imensa maioria dos dados utilizados em nossos programas são originados de arquivos (planilhas, PDFs, etc) ou bancos de dados e a forma de compartilhar eles com a comunidade não é trivial.

Talvez para quem não pertença a comunidade `R` pareça besteira; que estamos muito apegados a detalhes. Porém, [como o @DanielFalbel comentou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6704/duas-vezes-uma-pergunta-sobre-r-veio-erroneamente-para-o-meta#comment25896_6704) a comunidade `R` parece estar unida nesta posição.

## Qual pergunta deve se tornar wiki?

> Sugiro escolher uma dessas duas perguntas, transformar em wiki da comunidade e transferir para o site principal. Da forma como estão, aqui no meta, elas não cumprem nenhum papel.

Acredito que a proposta do @CarlosCinelli deva ocorrer com a [primeira pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) por se mais velha e mais votada.

Comment: *"O primeiro deles diz respeito ao fato de que de um modo geral quem começa a programar em R (...) não vem de uma cultura de ciência da computação e similares. São biólogos, nutricionistas, estatísticos, economistas e outras diversas profissões que apenas querem utilizar um software estatístico para desempenhar esta ou aquela tarefa."* Isso não muda o fato de que tanto as perguntas quanto o site são sobre programação. Eu seguiria as regras do Biology mesmo sem ser biólogo se eu fosse perguntar lá.

Comment: @Renan, vc está certo no que você está falando, considerando o site como um todo a pergunta está off-topic, mas essa pergunta está adequada dentro da comunidade R. Se você navegar pelo site, vai facilmente encontrar perguntas que são consideradas off-topic mas que ficaram lá porque a comunidade aceitou [Exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6703/6036). O nosso ponto é: a comunidade molda o que é aceito e neste caso, a pergunta está sendo aceita pela comunidade, por isso me parece errôneo migrar para cá, sendo que os principais interessados não concordam com o motivo.

Comment: De qualquer forma, aqui no Meta a pergunta também está off-topic. Essa pergunta não é diretamente relacionada ao uso do site, é simplesmente um: `como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível?` pode ser para o stack Overflow ou para qualquer outra coisa que der na telha.

Comment: Fiz uma outra pergunta eliminado a parte meta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-funções-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r 
cc @DanielFalbel

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Pode ser a minha ignorância sobre R, mas eu não consigo não achar essas perguntas estranhas, tanto no SOpt quanto no SOen. Os bullets da nova pergunta não valem pra qualquer linguagem? O que tem o R de tão particular em relação a esses pontos? Não estou tentando me opor ao que vocês querem fazer, quero entender melhor os motivos de as comunidades de R aqui e lá se organizarem tão fortemente para isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto são funções específicas do R, dput, set.seed, read.table, library, sessionInfo não acredito que as funções sejam as mesmas em toda linguagem

Comment: Eu poderia fazer a pergunta oposta: como que elencar funções para reproduzir a estrutura de dados ou fixar a semente de dados aleatórios é  algo do meta? A tarefa do ponto de vista de programação é clara - garantir um exemplo reproduzível em R - e existem funções específicas que são adequadas para resolver essa tarefa. Não tem nada meta ali, ninguém está discutindo como se comportar no site.

Comment: Nem estou mais discutindo se é meta ou não é @CarlosCinelli. Nem o meta é só pra discutir como se comportar no site. Em qualquer linguagem existem ferramentas específicas que ajudam nessas tarefas. E não existe nenhuma pergunta como essas no site sobre outras linguagens. Então, para quem está acostumado a olhar para o site como um todo, não tem como não achar estranho. Mas vamos ver no que dá a pergunta então. Você pretende postar aquela mesma resposta?

Comment: @bfavaretto parece estranho mesmo! A grande diferença é que a maioria dos usuários de R não são programadores e isso gera bastante dificuldade na hora de fazer perguntas. A maioria das pessoas que programam em R não rodam um script do início ao fim, elas rodam algumas linhas de código sem respeitar a ordem e sem abrir uma nova sessão a cada vez. Existe até pacote para criar exemplos reproduzíveis: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex e o termo `reprex` é fortemente adotado na comunidade. Pra gente é importante ensinar a fazer exemplo mínimo direito, faz parte de aprender a programar em R

Comment: Acho que a maior prova da necessidade destas perguntas ser reconhecida pela comunidade é que a primeira pergunta [seria a segunda mais votada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=votes&pageSize=50) com a tag [`R`] e a segunda seria a terceira empada com mais algumas.

Comment: Acho que os pontos de vista foram expostos a exaustão. Como encaminhamos a questão? Nenhuma das perguntas será movida e utilizaremos [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/)?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos acho que essa é a melhor forma! Mas acho que a sua resposta na segunda já se encaixa.

Comment: Considerando que já existe uma nova pergunta, inclusive mais detalhada, acho melhor usar essa nova mesmo, Tomás.