# Minha pergunta perdeu a tag, e agora? Deixar assim? Ou por tag apropriada?

Tags: suporte, tags

Fiz uma [pergunta sobre Tcl/Tk](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309210/64969) ano passado, na época em que existia/criei a tag Tcl/Tk (não lembro se eu que criei ou se já existia).

Porém, agora minha questão está [untagged](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged). Ao olhar o [histórico da questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/309210/revisions) não encontrei quais foram as tags originais que usei.

Deixar a questão com [untagged](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) me incomoda ([vide](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6483/e-aquelas-perguntas-que-n%c3%a3o-tem-tags#comment25117_6483)). Mas não consigo imaginar qual seria a tag mais apropriada a se colocar. Principalmente porque, se colocar a antiga (que creio ser `tcl-tk` ou semelhante) ela voltará a cair em desuso e voltará a essa situação deplorável de [untagged](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: Acho que vale add uma _tag_ sim. Caso ela não se encaixe em uma existente, crie (como já foi feito). Se com o tempo cair em desuso e sumir, cria de novo =p

Comment: untagged é uma tag para indicar que não tem tag ? É diferente de não ter nenhuma tag ?

Comment: Eu não entendo nada de Wish nem Tcl-lang, mas me parece que o problema e solução foi algo na linguagem e não em uma configuração do Wish, de inicio pensei em sugerir "por que não [wish]?", mas ao ler a solução me parece que [tcl] é a tag. Volto a dizer que não domino em nada o assunto, só li por cima o https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/tcltk/examples/buttons/. Note que apesar de não sermos o SOen, lá existe ambas tags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk. Realmente gostaria de saber se elas atenderiam a nossa comunidade também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [wish] tenho quase certeza de não ter usado. Talvez eu tenha usado [tcl] ou [tcl-tk], mas certeza que não usei [tk]. Eu gostaria de usar uma tag que atenda a comunidade, usar uma tag que vá sofrer coleção não é interessante pra comunidade, por isso abri essa questão

Comment: @Isac exatamente. Normalmente elas são derivadas de perguntas migradas, mas pelo visto também podem advir de tags abandonadas/coletadas pelo "GC"

Comment: Entendo, então sua duvida é porque removeram a tag da comunidade, como `[untagged]` só pode ser usado por moderadores, realmente eu não sei o porque disto ter ocorrido.